# How to add native language support in website for different mobile operators?

Tags: android, mobile, windows-mobile, transliteration, hindi

It is already very tough to show native language support (Hindi, Bengali, Urdu etc) in web browsers like Internet Explorer. But how do we give support in mobile browsers like opera mini, windows browser? If there is no possible way, then what can be possible alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

for android , same html should work as on desktop web browsers when you talk about languages.

however , you might want to support multiple screens to make it look well no matter what is the screen of the device :

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/overview.html

and also read some nice tips:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/best-practices.html

i think that the same hold for windows phone and iphone . all have about the same standard about languages.

Comment: Does it support fonts so well?

Comment: as far as i can say , yes. if you wish , i can test the website for you and show you a screenshot of what i see (i have galaxy s3) . also , you can easily download the android sdk (free and work on linux,pc and mac) to test it out on an emulator : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html .  do note that it might not work so well on the emulator (especially in speed ) , but it's a good start in case you don't have any android device.